# How to install additionnal python package in our Anaconda environnement

Tags: python-3.x, package, anaconda3, pynput

I would like to install the pynput package in my Anaconda environment but unfortunately it is not in the list of available packages. I think I have to add it externally but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone give me a solution?

I tried to install it from Anaconda but it doesn't appear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.